# Computing $\displaystyle \int{ \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x})^2}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int{\sqrt[3]{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}\over \sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x})^2}dx$$
I think i need to make a substitution but am having difficulties because of the different roots.
$$\int \left(\sqrt{x \over x+1}+1\right)^2 \sqrt[4]{x \over x+1}dx$$

Comment: For the first one put $x=y^{12}$, for the second $y^4=\frac{x}{x+1}$. The roots are denominators in rational exponents. We look at the least common multiple of those denominators.

Comment: You should post one problem per question. Create a new question for your second integral.

Comment: @Nathanson im not sure would work for the second one..never mind it looks like it will..i was right the first time it wont

Comment: @BozoVulicevic See the computation below.

Comment: Why are you interested in computing this integral? Where did it arise?

Comment: @CarlMummert These are text-book exercises.  Why is any student interested in being able to compute text-book exercises? And more importantly, why are you asking those questions?

Comment: @Nathanson: because there is (obviously) an infinite number of possible integrals, so they cannot all be on-topic. I am asking whether there is any particular reason to look at this integral. If there is not - if it is just a textbook exercise - then the asker should spend some time to formulate a better-composed question that actually brings out a *mathematical* issue. As it stands, the post is not very well composed.  In fact, it does not even pose a question, it just states an integral.

Comment: @CarlMummert Ridiculous. Go try to write a book in which there are no examples of the infinite number of possible integrals. Just stop wasting everyone's time and do something useful like actually answering or posting  math questions. This question is perfectly written.

Comment: @Nathanson: I am amazed at such direct comments from someone so new to the site. There are many members here who look for real quality in questions. This site is for mathematics at all levels. But there are well-composed and poorly-composed questions of all levels, and this question has much room for improvement.

Comment: @CarlMummert That is what happens when all your assumptions are incorrect. You get amazed. Just stop wasting everyone's time. I only wanted to give a proper reply such that the OP doesn't feel intimidated by your first comment (because I know from what direction you are comming). His post is perfectly written. Unless you have some math to talk about this is my last reply.

Comment: @Nathanson: the post *does not even state a question*. It is far from perfectly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y^4=\frac{x}{x+1}$ then $x=\frac{y^4}{1-y^4}$ and $dx=\left(\frac{y^4}{1-y^4}\right)'dy$, which is rational.

Then 
$$\begin{align}\int\left(\sqrt{x \over x+1}+1\right)^2 \sqrt[4]{x \over x+1}dx&=\int\left(y^2+1\right)^2\cdot y\cdot\left(\frac{y^4}{1-y^4}\right)'dy\end{align}$$

The integrand in the right-hand side is a rational function. We have an algorithm to compute these (partial fraction decomposition ...).

---

This is a particular case of the following type of integrals:

$$\int R\left(x,\sqrt[n]{\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}}\right)dx$$
where $R(x,y)$ is a rational function. All of these can be rationalized by the change of variable $y^n=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$.

In your exercise

$$\int\left(\sqrt{x \over x+1}+1\right)^2 \sqrt[4]{x \over x+1}dx=\int\left[\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{x}{x+1}}\right)^2+1\right]\sqrt[4]{\frac{x}{x+1}}dx$$

It has the form above for $R(x,y)=(y^2+1)^2\cdot y$, $n=4$, $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=1$, and $d=1$. This writing becomes apparent after you turn the radicals to a common denominator.

---

The first exercise is also a particular case of this type of integrals.

We can write (turning the exponents to a common denominator)

$$\begin{align}\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x})^2}dx&=\int\frac{(\sqrt[12]{x})^6+2(\sqrt[12]{x})^3}{(\sqrt[12]{x})^6((\sqrt[12]{x})^6+(\sqrt[12]{x})^4)^2}dx\end{align}$$

We can take $R(x,y)=\frac{y^6+2y^3}{y^6(y^6+y^4)^2}$, $n=12$, $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=0$, and $d=1$.